# Java: Moving Cursor Forward/Backward in a doubly linked list

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

Like a normal linked list, I have a node class and a doublelinkedlist class. The head, tail, and cursor are all initially set to null. After adding an element, the cursor will be set to the newly added element. Let's say I have added two elements so far, the cursor is referencing the second element (because it was just added). How do I move the cursor back so it references the first element? In addition, how do I move it forward again to the second element?

Answer (score 0):

Your question and purpose is not very clear, anyway to traverse through java collection framework's LinkedList ( the linked list in java collection api ) you can use an Iterator object. So that the cursor will sequentially traverse from one object to the other until it reaches the end.

I hope below link will be useful.

https://beginnersbook.com/2014/07/java-linkedlist-iterator-example/

Comment: I am not looking to transverse a doublylist, I just want to move one index backwards

Comment: @WangWang So, are you trying to implement the list? By "How to move the cursor backwards", do you actually mean "How to implement a method on a doubly linked list class so that the user of the class can move the cursor backwards"?

Comment: @ShioT yes, backwards by 1

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, Java doesn't have a doubly linked list class. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Would you perhaps like to know how to do it if it were a custom built doubly linked list?

```
// Class for Doubly Linked List 
public class DLL { 
    Node head; // head of list 

    /* Doubly Linked list Node*/
    class Node { 
        int data; 
        Node prev; 
        Node next; 

        // Constructor to create a new node 
        // next and prev is by default initialized as null 
        Node(int d) { data = d; } 
    } 
} 

public class DLLTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // setup
        Node cursor = new Node(1);
        cursor.next = new Node(2);

        Node temp = cursor;
        cursor = cursor.next;
        cursor.prev = temp;


        // To move cursor to second node, overwrite cursor with next node
        cursor = cursor.next;

        // To move cursor to first node, overwrite cursor again
        cursor = cursor.prev;
    }
}
```

Implementation of DLL from: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/doubly-linked-list/

Comment: The Node class here is not a static class and thus each Node contains a reference to the parent object. The memory footprint is not going to look good.

Comment: So change it to static class Node {...}. That should fix it, right? And could you site a website where I can read more about this.

Comment: I think googling "Java inner class" would give you what you want